# react-table/react-table.css cause test to crash on compile

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, jestjs, react-table

I have code that works and tests that work. I only have one problem in my react-table file. The api for react-table.js says to use their css file I need in my react-table.js file `import "react-table/react-table.css";` but when I do this my test crash on compile. I'm using basically a copy of the example of simple table on the react-table.js webpage. How do I use their css file and still get my test to run?

this is the error I get If I dont comment out the css import
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For testing, you need to mock the css/image imports

```
  "jest": {    
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      ".*\\.(css|scss|sass)$": "path/to/styleMock.js",
      ".*\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "path/to/assetMock.js"
    },
```

*(Make sure you adjust the path to the mock files appropriately)*

**styleMock.js**

```
module.exports = {}
```

**assetMock.js**

```
module.exports = 'IMAGE_MOCK'
```

Reference: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/webpack#handling-static-assets

Comment: i just had to do a npm install --save-dev identity-obj-proxy and add the jest stuff from https://jestjs.io/docs/en/webpack#handling-static-assets for Mocking CSS Modules to my package.json and it worked.